# /etc/X11/xorg.conf file is not available

Tags: xorg, laptop, display

I am using Sony VPCZ136GG Laptop. Os Ubuntu 11.10

/etc/X11/xorg.conf file is not available.

I can set only 1600 x 900(16:9) resolution. Not able to connect Projector. I want to add multiple screen resolution. How to do this.

```
lspci | grep "VGA"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation GT216 [GeForce GT 330M] (rev a2)
```

when i am upgrading always coming this error

! https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMjWn.jpg

I am using,intel VGA. I disabled nVidia card, because 3D is not working wile using nVidia.

Note: 
I upgraded from ubuntu 11.04 to 11.10 after that i am getting this problem

Answer (score 1):

The configuration file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` is optional, and it is not present by default. You can create one if you wish, but the easiest way to get an external display working is to go to system menu (the "power cog" icon at the top-right corner of the screen) > Displays. This should almost definitely work with the Intel driver.

Comment: yes, is ther. My projector display is not in proper. I followed this link also,display is not coming http://www.baibhav.com.np/article/6-computer-tips-a-tricks/32-projector-external-monitor-display-problem-on-ubuntu-1110-solved-.html